# Trans.commit for Connection.Query

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I have a function below where it will insert values into a SQL database through a stored procedure. I am trying to implement a `trans.commit` to make it better but I keep hitting error at the first insert using the stored procedure of `sp_insertTransaction2` :

> ExecuteReader requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized

I saw a lot of tutorials online but there are using `SqlCommand` to initialize the *trans* instead of using connection. Query like my code. Help needed to fix on the issue.

```
public bool insertTransactions(string receiver, string deliverer, string module, DateTime date, bool isChkout, int timeLapse, List<Lot> Lots)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var trans = connection.BeginTransaction();

        try
        {
            var data = connection.Query<TransactionsModel>("[sp_insertTransaction2]",
            new
            {
                receiver,
                deliverer,
                module,
                date,
                isChkout,
                timeLapse
            },
            commandTimeout: 120, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            trans.Commit();

            foreach (var lot in Lots)
            {
                var data2 = connection.Query<TransactionsModel>("[sp_insertLot]",
                 new
                {
                    lot.LotVPO,
                    lot.Bin,
                    lot.Location,
                    lot.Qty,
                },
                 commandTimeout: 120, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            trans.Commit();
       }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("insertTransactions API error : " + ex.ToString());
            trans.Rollback();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your stored procedures, judging by the name, do the insertion, right? Therefore, use the `Execute` method to call them instead of `Query`.

Comment: For a basic bulk insert, consider using `SqlBulkCopy`.

Answer (score 1):

You are correctly starting the transaction with `connection.BeginTransaction();`  but you need to input the transaction var `trans` in each `Query<>()`. There is an IDbTransaction method parameter.

Also, you can't commit a transaction twice. You need to begin a new one if actually needed but **usually** you do all your queries within one transaction and commit at the very end.

Comment: do you have example on how to input the transaction var trans to the Query<>()? I searched for the IDbTransaction online but none with the Query<>() code case.

Comment: @LiaLucindia First of all, I assume you're using Dapper from looking at your code. Try for example adding `, transaction: trans` at the end of your method parameters. Your IDE, if you're using one, should assist you.

Comment: this works. I just need to specify the trans before commandTimeout: 120 and it will work. } trans, commandTimeout: 120... thank you for your help!

Comment: i disagree with the answer, if the code works doesn't means it is the correct usage of transactions

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have multiple `commit`, with one of them in the for loop.

Transaction means everything complete successfully, or something failed and triggered rollback.

If what your intention is to save the transaction record together with its lot number then you can only commit once, otherwise it will result in an error

dapper provides a better class `TransactionScope` that will automatically rollback if the code did not execute `scope.Complete()`

Also, `Query` is for reading rows, for insert/update/delete use `Execute` and use `using` statements for both your connection and transactionscope so it will be closed automatically

```
public bool insertTransactions(string receiver, string deliverer, string module, DateTime date, bool isChkout, int timeLapse, List<Lot> Lots)
{
    try
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var scope = new TransactionScope()) // use scope instead, its better
                {   //use Execute when you insert/update/delete, Query is only for read
                    var data = connection.Execute<TransactionsModel>("[sp_insertTransaction2]",
                    new {
                    receiver,
                    deliverer,
                    module,
                    date,
                    isChkout,
                    timeLapse
                    }, commandTimeout: 120, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

                    foreach (var lot in Lots)
                    {
                        //use Execute when you insert/update/delete, Query is only for read
                        var data2 = connection.Execute<TransactionsModel>("[sp_insertLot]",
                        new
                        {
                        lot.LotVPO,
                        lot.Bin,
                        lot.Location,
                        lot.Qty,
                        }, commandTimeout: 120, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                
                    }
                    scope.Complete(); //Or it will automatically rollback, call it only once! 
                }
                
            }   
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("insertTransactions API error : " + ex.ToString());
            trans.Rollback();
            return false;
        }
}
```